# ES6 & Webpack: import not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm currently learning ES6 & Webpack, and I've have a particular set of files that the `import` statement just won't work on. Here's the problem:

**Sagas.js**

```
import { deleteMe } from './DeleteMe';
import * as constants from '../Constants';

debugger;
```

**DeleteMe.js**

```
export const deleteMe = "Yep, it's loading";
console.log(deleteMe);
```

In the above file, `deleteMe` is not accessible from debugger (with Chrome Inspector). `constants` is.

And Constants.js

```
export const SET_COMMENTS = 'SET_COMMENTS';
```

Before debugger halts (in Chrome inspector), the "Yep, it's loading" *does* fire in the console, so the file itself is coming through.

I've tried:

- `import * as deleteMeStuff from ./DeleteMe` to see if `deleteMeStuff` would populate. It doesn't
- Restarting webpack-dev-server. No dice, no errors on compile. Throwing a `debugger` in ./DeleteMe confirms changes are coming through.
- `const deleteMe = "Yep, it's working"; export default deleteMe` & `import deleteMe from './DeleteMe'` --> still no joy

At the debugger, I've just noticed `_DeleteMe` returns `{deleteMe: "Yep, it's loading", __esModule: true}`

Any idea what's going on here & how to fix it? I'm thoroughly confused. There are a ton of other import files working successfully in other files across my app.

Comment: FWIW, your exports and imports are fine (assuming Webpack is okay with there being no file extension). If I do this directly in Chrome (now that it has module support) without Webpack and add the file extensions, the imported `deleteMe` is present. So this is a Webpack config issue, I'm guessing.

Comment: `const deleteMe = "Yep, it's loading"; export { deleteMe };` then `import { deleteMe } from './DeleteMe';`

Comment: One thought: Is there anything else in Sagas.js other than what you've shown? Webpack may be tree-shaking and seeing that you don't use `deleteMe` and so not bothering to import it.

Comment: What do you mean by `deleteMe is not accessible from debugger`? I assume the code is transpiled by babel so the constant name might be changed to something else or even replaced with an expression to follow ES2015 modules behaviour `(0, _ModuleName.deleteMe)`

Comment: @TJ Tree shaking was an excellent  idea, but throwing a console.log(deleteMe) into `Sagas.js` works just fine(???). And yet a debugger on the next line still fails to find `deleteMe`. @Yury Admittedly I'm new to ES6/Babel/Webpack - this sounds feasible. Is there a means of chasing down changed constant names in Chrome inspector? Also, wouldn't  those changed names show in Chrome Inspector --> sources? (They show as `deleteMe`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use default and const in same line like

```
export default const deleteMe = "Yep, it's working"
```

You have to break it like:

```
export const deleteMe = "Yep, it's loading";
export default deleteMe;
```

and to import it you can do any one of following:

```
import deleteMe  from './DeleteMe';
```

or

```
import  { deleteMe }  from './DeleteMe';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggest vijay. The `default`  argument listed in the 3rd bullet point was just an experiment to try to track down the problem, can confirm it still has the same behaviour when the `default` argument is split onto two lines. I've edited the 3rd bullet point above to clarify. The problem behavior still exists.

Comment: This answer has some wrong syntax. First of all you have to include `{}` when you import anything which is not exported with `default` keyword. If exported with `default` keyword, then you can directly import it without `{}`. 

Also you don't have to do `export const deleteMe = "Yep, it's loading";` and then `export default deleteMe;`. 

You can export it in one `export` keyword after `const deleteMe` has defined. 

No problem you'll get it as you go ahead in JS field !